# Is it a good practice to store both the Google Oauth2 access token and the refresh token in the database un hashed?

Tags: google, oauth, jwt, access-token

I recently came across a source code where they save a user's refresh token and the access token upon sign in through Google into the database. This is done to access the Google APIs later on through the server.

My question is, isn't this insecure? This is like storing the passwords plaintext in the database. If the database gets hacked, then anyone can use those credentials to wreak havoc using the Google API. By the way, those users will have permission to add and edit users in a Google Workspace.

Comment: You can’t hash them because unlike passwords you need to be able to provide the original values. That said plaintext is probably the wrong answer and encrypted is a better one, with the challenges of managing the crypto keys.